# How to make asynchronous Kafka messages

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I want to send an object from App1 to App2 update it then return it to App1.

Currently the object doesnt get updated and App1 prints the object it initialy sent in the callback funciton. I need App1 to wait for data to be proccessed in App2 first.

App1:

```
@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, ParsingInfo> kafkaTemplate;
...

System.out.println("sending message to App2");
CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, ParsingInfo>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(Properties.TopicNames.PARSE, parsingInfo);
// create listener and wait for response for CompletableFuture
future.whenCompleteAsync((result, ex) -> 
{
    System.out.println("get results");
    if (ex != null) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error sending message: " + ex.getMessage());
    } else {
        ParsingInfo newInfo = new ParsingInfo();
        newInfo.copyFrom(result.getProducerRecord().value());
        System.out.println("success-getProducerRecord 0: " + newInfo.getSopSaveData());
    }
});
```

App2:

```
KafkaListener(topics = KafkaProperties.TopicNames.PARSE, groupId = KafkaProperties.ConsumerGroupIds.SMART_INTERPRETER)
public CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, ParsingInfo>> listen(ParsingInfo parsingInfo) 
{
    System.out.println("Received Message: " + parsingInfo.getSopSaveData());
    CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, ParsingInfo>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try 
    {
        parsingInfo.setSopSaveData("test");
        System.out.println("Sending Message: " + parsingInfo.getSopSaveData());
        future.complete(new SendResult<String, ParsingInfo>(new ProducerRecord<String, ParsingInfo>(KafkaProperties.TopicNames.PARSE, parsingInfo), null));
        return future;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
        return future;
    }
}
```

i've add @EnableAsync to producer and consumer but no luck. Is this type of logic possible?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to come back to theory and reevaluate for yourself what is `producer` and `consumer` in messaging and how broker is involved in between.
Doesn't matter what messaging system you use, the behavior is much the same.

So, when we publish the data into broker, we say into what destination to put that data. When data has reached that destination successfully, the producer receives a confirmation. And that's it: the work of the producer is done. The consumer on that destination might not exist at all. That's a general purpose of messaging: distinguishing data producing and data consuming in a reliable manner.

No close to the ground. According to your `@KafkaListener`, you indeed expect to produce some data as a reply. So, consider to use a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/sending-messages.html#replying-template